# Consistent Linux device enumeration

Tags: linux, usb-device

In our Linux box we have USB -> serial device which was always identified as
`/dev/ttyACM0`. So I've written an application and until yesterday, everything worked fine. But suddenly (yeah, during the remote presentation ...) the device stopped working. After quick research, I found that the connection changed to `/dev/ttyACM1`. It was a little untimely, but now I have a problem - how to unambiguously identify my device? Like, for example, the storage drive could be initialized using UUID although the `/dev/sd**` has changed. Is there some way to do that for serial devices?

Now I use a stupid workaround:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    m_port = std::string("/dev/ttyACM") + (char)('0' + i);
    m_fd = open(m_port.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
}
```

The [link](https://numato.com/product/2-channel-usb-powered-relay-module) to the device we use.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since we are talking USB devices and assuming you have udev, you could setup some udev rules.

I guess, and this is just a wild guess, somebody or something unplugged/removed the device and plugged it back in/added the device again, which bumps up the number.

Now, first you need vendor and product id's:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0403:6001 FTDI FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

Next, you need the serial number (in case you have several):

```
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep '{serial}' | head -n1
    ATTRS{serial}=="A6008isP"
```

Now, lets create a udev rule:

UDEV rules are usually scattered into many files in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. Create a new file called `99-usb-serial.rules` and put the following line in there, I have three devices, each with a a different serial number:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A6008isP", SYMLINK+="MySerialDevice"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A7004IXj", SYMLINK+="MyOtherSerialDevice"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="FTDIF46B", SYMLINK+="YetAnotherSerialDevice"

ls -l /dev/MySerialDevice
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 25 22:12 /dev/MySerialDevice -> ttyUSB1
```

If you do not want the serial number, any device from vendor with same chip will then get the same symlink, only one can be plugged in at any given time.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="MySerialDevice"
```

[Taken from here](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/)

Comment: If you have a recent linux distribution, most likely it already automatically creates the device as `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-XXXX_USB2.0-Serial-if00-port0`. This might be enough for you without custom udev rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, many no-name devices all have the serial number "0123456789abcdef". That's where it gets interesting.

Comment: @mosvy are serial numbers unchangable?

Comment: @OganM they may be changed ... if you're able to root the devices.

Answer (score 0):

UDEV rules is  good idea
but many devices hasn't serial
or has same serial
and that does not solve the problem ttyACM0 to ttyACM1

Try

> systemctl stop ModemManager
>   systemctl disable ModemManager

P.S.
I'm not a magician, I'm just learning, but friendship helps us do real miracles